# How to generate push notifications (Android) if the database is updated

Tags: android, database, notifications

I want to send notification to the Android app every time the database is updated. We have a server and the application has a form which adds values to the database, so every time the database is updated, the user should receive notifications.

Can someone point me to the tutorials or post the code.

Comment: You should to use GCM - Google Cloud Message which has to be implemented on both sides - the server and the app.

Comment: You should explain what you have already tried.